# How to run a C++ exe file from Java?

Tags: java, exe

I want to open an EXE file from a Java program. I tried 2 procedures.
The program can run some programs, like NotePad++, but cannot run my C++ EXE file. I tried:

1. `Process exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file.getAbsolutePath());`
2. `ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());`

but neither of the above work. No exception is thrown, and `exec.isAlive = true`.

Comment: If `isAlive` is true then the app was launched (verify with Task Manager). If your C++ program is not functioning correctly then it has to be a problem with your C++ app, not with your Java app.  Debug your C++ app.

Comment: Make sure you’re reading the processes input/error streams and check the exitValue (you can call waitFor on the Process to wait till it exits)

Comment: In case of `ProcessBuilder`, you have to invoke `start()` on it. As MadProgrammer said, you have to make sure to handling the pipes to the subprocess, to prevent it from being blocked. Or redirect them to use the stdio of your process: `new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath()).inheritIO().start();`…

Answer (score -1):

Your mistake is that you took the absolute path in the first procedure.
Try using a relative path, I just tested and it worked just fine.

This also works for me (using 2 backslashs').
    `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\DDNet\\DDNet.exe");`

Kind regards

Comment: That's not true, It's not important at all, I said No Exception thrown.